# Closing SQL connections in regular ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Anyone know what the best practice is for closing connections in Regular ASP, should I do it immediately after each sql query or just at the bottom of the page?

For instance, is this OK:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM tblUSER"
set rstemp = connTemp.execute(sql)
theCount = rstemp("num")

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num2 FROM tblCUSTOMER"
set rstemp = connTemp.execute(sql)
theCount2 = rstemp("num2")
rstemp.close
set rstemp = nothing
```

or should I close the connection after each connection like this:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM tblUSER"
set rstemp = connTemp.execute(sql)
theCount = rstemp("num")
rstemp.close
set rstemp = nothing

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num2 FROM tblCUSTOMER"
set rstemp = connTemp.execute(sql)
theCount2 = rstemp("num2")
rstemp.close
set rstemp = nothing
```

(If we close the connection after each query, will it use more or less resources, will it increase or decrease locks, etc)

Comment: I don't see any code that closes an actual connection in the above examples.  `rstemp.close` is closing a recordset, but the connection `connTemp` is still open.  Also, in the first example, the second call to `set rstemp = connTemp.execute(sql)` is creating a new recordset object and discarding the old recordset.  In essence, both examples are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

The general rule of thumb is to re-use as much as possible. Closing and reopening the connection for each query will increase your overhead unnecessarily and also possibly create issues with the connection pooling (if your are running lots and lots of queries in a short space of time.)

Hope this helps.
Dave

Comment: True, the bottom line is close the connection in the bottom of the page, or even better right after the last code using it.

Comment: And make sure that any redirect is happening after closing the last connection: `if redirectURL <> "" then
 response.redirect(redirectURL)
end if`

Answer (score 0):

For every page I write, I open a single connection object, then use that same connection object for all my recordsets as the "ActiveConnection" property of the recordset, then close the connection object when I'm done working.

Example:

```
Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
cn.Open MyDsnString

Dim rs1
Set rs1 = CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
rs1.ActiveConnection = cn
rs1.source = "some query"
rs1.Open

'... (stuff happens here) '

rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing

'... (stuff happens here) '

Dim rs2
Set rs2 = CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
rs2.ActiveConnection = cn
rs2.source = "select something from sometable"
rs2.Open

'... (stuff happens here) '

rs2.Close
Set rs2 = Nothing

'... (stuff happens here) '

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

That way there's only one connection open for the entire page, and it's very efficient.